# Permission denied while running command Cmake

Tags: cmake

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. While I run command  `cmake --version` I get Permission denied error, as below:

```
 :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cmake", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('cmake==3.18.4.post1', 'console_scripts', 'cmake')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cmake-3.18.4.post1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/__init__.py", line 46, in cmake
    raise SystemExit(_program('cmake', sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cmake-3.18.4.post1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/__init__.py", line 42, in _program
    return subprocess.call([os.path.join(CMAKE_BIN_DIR, name)] + args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cmake-3.18.4.post1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake'
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Try running it with  sudo cmake --version

Comment: sudo cmake --version,  after running this still getting same error

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/cmake` would suggest you installed it outside of the Ubuntu package system. Do you have the Ubuntu version of cmake installed as well? What does `type -a cmake` say? What if you run `/usr/bin/cmake --version` instead?

Comment: I just follow 'Install CMake through the Ubuntu Command Line' section of  https://vitux.com/how-to-install-cmake-on-ubuntu-18-04/  and it works fine now

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: i have executed all this following command: 
```$ wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.15.2/cmake-3.15.2.tar.gz``` 
```$ tar -zxvf cmake-3.15.2.tar.gz``` ```$ cd cmake-3.15.2``` ```$./bootstrap```
```$ make ``` ```$ sudo make install``` ```$ cmake --version```
you can download tar.gz file from ```https://cmake.org/download```

Answer (score 0):

Works here as normal & root user installed from the Ubuntu sources.

```
zeus@zeus-H370M:~$ which cmake
zeus@zeus-H370M:~$
zeus@zeus-H370M:~$ su
Password: 

root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# apt install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cmake-data gcc gcc-9 libasan5 libatomic1
libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libgcc-9-dev libitm1
libjsoncpp1 liblsan0 libquadmath0 librhash0 libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
zeus@zeus-H370M:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

I would suggest a re-install from the Ubuntu sources.

```
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# cat /etc/os-release |grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```